# Selecting multiple data from the database at the same time

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

I am creating a java application that needs to collect loads of data, process the data into objects and return the objects as a list.

All of the data collected is from different tables in my database (some are joined but all of them are different SQL calls)

I was thinking of getting this data through different threads but since multiple threads cannot use the same connection to acess data in the database i would have to create a new connection for each of these threads.

My Question is: what is the best way to acess and process multiple data from database at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough memory I would use a full second level change that syncs to the database. Using a cache makes it extremely faster. If you won't have enough memory on the server/client you can cache your query on the sqlserver with a table that has all the values from your query and this table gets updated every second.

Otherwise you can use a Threadpool with Threads which inserts the queryresults into a shared object for the result.

Comment: how do you create a second level change? this is the first time im hearing about this

Comment: When you are using JPA  you normally cache every queryresult in a first-level cache inside the entitymanager. When you define caching for entities these entities are getting stored inside your memory as a second level cache. 

You can read more about this in the JPA specification chapter 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Spring framework`.Suppose there is ModelBean class present where all constants are declared.In ModelBean class name is field which are declared.

```
public class CurriculumReportDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport{
   public List<String> fetchList(){
      String query="";
      List<ModelBean > tempList=new ArrayList<ModelBean >();
      List<Map<String,Object>> record = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query);

      for(Map<String,Object> result=record){
         /*create new instance of ModelBean*/
         model=new ModelBean();
         /*"name" is the column name which are fetch from db*/
         model.setName(result.get("name").toString);
         /*now set model in tempList*/
         tempList.add(ModelBean );
      }

      return tempList;
   }
}
```

If you have many connection Then you can create many List here and set into ModelBean class.
I think this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response - the only thing i need to do with my connection is basicly: 1. Open connection 2. execute selectStatement 3. Close connection. but i have around 5 threads that needs to do this, is the Spring framework still a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the database should be designed in such a way that you should be able to get all the related data in a single query(maybe with JOINS). Not sure if that is possible to achieve in your case.

There are three viable options, one you have already tried by creating multiple threads and fetching the data. I will just add an input to that approach and you may try in case that optimizes. Create Data Fetcher threads to fetch the data from different tables and create one Data Processor thread to process the data as it is fetched by Data Fetcher threads.

or

Second approach can be to to create a stored procedure, which will run directly on the database and can do some data processing for you. This will avoid the need of creating too many threads and doing a lot of processing in your java code.

or

Mix both the approaches to achieve the best results.

Good luck!

Comment: My program collects data and process it and then display it as many different charts because of this all data are more or less different and can only be selected one at a time